# How to get all the image from firebase storage in android studio?

Tags: android, image

```
storageReference = firebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        ref = storageReference.child("images/1808185");
    File rootpath = new File(Constants.getDLibImageDirectoryPath());
    if(!rootpath.exists()){
        rootpath.mkdirs();
    }

    final File localfile = new File (rootpath,"1808185.jpg");

    ref.getFile(localfile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Log.e("firebase ",";local tem file created  created " +localfile.toString());
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e("firebase ",";local tem file not created  created " +e.toString());
        }
    });
```

Here are my codes that are only available to get 1 image instead of multiple images.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase, currently there are no API call that can give you list of all files in Firebase Storage. Instead what you can do is, Once image is uploaded to Firebase Storage, get the download link of that image using getDownloadUrl(); and save it to real-time database.

To read or write data from the database, you need an instance of DatabaseReference:

```
private DatabaseReferencedatabaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

To save link of the uploaded image to real time database, you need to create java object such as:

```
public class Image implements Serializable {
public String downloadUrl;

public Image() {
}

public Image(String dUrl) {
    this.downloadUrl = dUrl;
}
```

}

Once you created java object, Add following lines of code in onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot):

```
Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
Image image = new Image(downloadUri.toString());
String userId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
databaseReference.child(userId).setValue(image);
```

This will add download link of that image in real-time database. Now when you want list of all the images in your Firebase Storage, simply use the following code:

```
private ArrayList<Data> list;.
private void getImagesList() {
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Data data = new 
               Data(childSnapshot.child("downloadUrl").getValue().toString());
            list.add(data);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
});}
```